# Java Bluetooth fails to detect

Tags: java, bluetooth

I'm trying to code up a program that allows me to detect nearby bluetooth connections. However, it's been throwing me a null array problem, and it doesn't detect my phone's bluetooth connectivity.

```
import javax.bluetooth.LocalDevice;
import javax.bluetooth.RemoteDevice;

import java.io.IOException;

// import javax.bluetooth.BluetoothStateException;
import javax.bluetooth.DiscoveryAgent;

public class Greenteeth {
    public Greenteeth() throws IOException {
        LocalDevice device = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
        
        
        RemoteDevice[] remoteDevice = device.getDiscoveryAgent().retrieveDevices(DiscoveryAgent.PREKNOWN);
        
        if (remoteDevice == null) {
            System.out.println("0");
        }
        
        for (RemoteDevice d : remoteDevice) {
            System.out.print("DEVICE NAME: " + d.getFriendlyName(false));
            System.out.println("GREENTEETH ADDRESS: " + d.getBluetoothAddress() + "\n");
        }
        
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what's going on as I followed a youtube tutorial that outlined the steps to take to set up this code, and I don't see differences in the code.

I'm pretty sure I hooked up the JAR file correctly as the imports work fine.

And here's the error message AND OUTPUT:

```
BlueCove version 2.1.1-SNAPSHOT on winsock
0            // prints because array is null
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read the array length because "remoteDevice" is null
    at Greenteeth.<init>(Greenteeth.java:20)
    at Home$ConnectBT.actionPerformed(Home.java:120)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6614)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6379)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4990)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4822)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4919)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4548)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4489)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2769)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4822)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: When `remoteDevice` is `null`, you print `0`, but then you continue and try to iterate over the array.

Comment: @tgdavies the problem is that it's not detecting nearby bluetooth connections tho

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert at Java, but I believe I can provide you some lead based on the source code.

To establish a Bluetooth connection first you should **discover devices**. If we check how such a [discovery can be performed](http://www.bluecove.org/bluecove/apidocs/javax/bluetooth/DiscoveryAgent.html) in the used library:

> There are two ways to discover devices. First, an application may use
> startInquiry() to start an inquiry to find devices in proximity to the
> local device. Discovered devices are returned via the
> deviceDiscovered() method of the interface DiscoveryListener. The
> second way to discover devices is via the retrieveDevices() method.
> This method will return devices that have been discovered via a
> previous inquiry or devices that are classified as pre-known.
> (Pre-known devices are those devices that are defined in the Bluetooth
> Control Center as devices this device frequently contacts.) The
> retrieveDevices() method does not perform an inquiry, but provides a
> quick way to get a list of devices that may be in the area.

Here this is the key part:

> This method will return devices that have been discovered via a
> previous inquiry or devices that are classified as pre-known.

Hence in the YouTube tutorial you watched, I believe tutor already discovered that device before, this is why s/he has no problems with it.

So, in your case, you should start an inquiry. The method is explained in the [source code](http://www.bluecove.org/bluecove/apidocs/javax/bluetooth/DiscoveryAgent.html#startInquiry(int,%20javax.bluetooth.DiscoveryListener)). I believe, your issue will be fixed if you perform an inquiry, but let's investigate further.

Now, let's check what `getRemoteDevice` to understand the error. The [source code](http://www.bluecove.org/bluecove/apidocs/javax/bluetooth/RemoteDevice.html#getRemoteDevice(javax.microedition.io.Connection)) explains the method thrown in your case as:

```
NullPointerException - if conn is null
```

Sadly, the provided link there does not work. But I assume, `null` might expected in some cases. Hence you should handle this with `try catch` method.

You can find an example code [here](http://www.java2s.com/example/java/javax.bluetooth/get-bluetooth-remote-device.html), also one good example is available in the [official library's website](http://www.bluecove.org/bluecove/apidocs/overview-summary.html#DeviceDiscovery) as well.

Finally, I suggest reading official documentations and trying basic examples that are provided in GitHub or official website etc. rather than following YouTube tutorials. You will benefit more in the long term I guarantee that.